# How to remove the substring after a dot in Amibroker?

Tags: stocks, trading

I am using Amibroker ver5.97

Suppose I have a stock symbol DAS.G and EFS.XF. I would like to remove the substring after the dot (including dot itself) so that the output becomes DAS and EFS respectively.

How can this be done in AFL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Explore:

```
Substring = StrFind(Name(),".");
Length = StrLen(Name());
Position = Length - (Length-Substring) - 1;

if ( Substring ) 
{
Ticker=StrLeft( Name(), Position);
}
else
{
Ticker=Name();
}

Filter = 1;
AddTextColumn(Ticker,"Ticker");
```